# login and post data using curl php

Tags: php, post, curl

i need to login to a website then it redirects me to an other page where i have to post data ; 
the code i already wrote is going to logged me on succeffuly and it redirects me to the page i have to post(send $_POST) data but i don't know how to post it (begining an other request using the some session/cookies that already started) this is the code .

```
$url = "http://site.com/account.php?s_id=&d=y";
    $email = "EMAIL@EMAIL.COM";
    $password = "PASS";
    $postfields = "email=$email&password=$password&submit=1&do=login&forward=&communicate=&communicate_id=1";
    $postfield = "message=doit";
    $cookiefile  = tempnam("/tmp", "cookies");  
    $agent     = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";  
    $ch = curl_init();
    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // Get the header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Allow redirection
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: what do you mean by posting data ? please clarify

Comment: Try not to follow location and parse the redirect answer and post in a subsequent call.

Comment: can you be more clear please? or give me some details with code example ?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

Comment: i do that already the problem is how to post in a subsqusequent with the same session/cookie already i created .

Answer (score 0):

To do a subsequent request with same session and cookie data, don't call `curl_exec($ch);` too early. Simply work with the same curl handle, changing options as you go on. Your code should look something like this:

```
// do login request
curl_exec($ch);
echo '<hr>';

// change url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_to_post_to);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_to_post);

// do post request with your data
curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```